# Flutter url launcher not working on release build

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to open dialer and sms app but its only working on debug mode when i make release build on run it on release its not working. I try everything

I already add this

```
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
```

Also flutter clean, upgrade not working

I also try to downgrade the plugin but stuck on this situation nothing is working for me

I try to run like this flutter run --release and its showing error that

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_
launcher)
```

This error mostly solve by close app and run but in release mode nothing is working for me.

Dont know why its working on debug then.